# Chinese Pinyin Puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

Puzzle World in VR[image] Chat. Must Select the 8 Words in the right order 1-8. Nothing other than that I'm aware of.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @ACB would it be Puzzle world in VR chat?

Answer (score 3):

This is from the VRchat world `[puzzle] CUBE ROOM !`.

The world isn't Chinese, it's Japanese. And no knowledge of Chinese (including pinyin) *or* Japanese is required.

The context of the earlier puzzles is important, because it sets up the rule: you need to

> select them in order of *how many enclosed regions* they have, from 0 to 7.